# jQuery Mobile Auto Dividers order by lowest number

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm building a jQuery Mobile list view and attempting to order by the closest person. I thought auto dividers might be the best means to achieve this, but I'm new to jQuery Mobile, so am open to better suggestions.

When I add the list items I detect the distance and pass it in via:

```
var listItem = $('<li data-distance="' + milesFromCorrespondent + '">');
```

And then in the autodividersSelector I am getting this value and grouping items by it:

```
$(list).listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr('data-distance');
            return out;
        }
    }).listview('refresh');
```

I have three values at the moment and they are ordered as follows:

3455
1094
1223

which is how they come out of my array.

Is it possible to order by lowest to high number in this manner or is there a better way to order a listview?

Here is my code in full:

```
function buildNearestCorrespondentList(correspondents) {
var list = $('#nearestCorrespondentsList');

// Find nearest correspondents
$.each(correspondents, function (index, item) {
    var milesFromCorrespondent = distance(deviceLocation[0], deviceLocation[1], item.latitude, item.longitude);

    var listItem = $('<li data-distance="' + milesFromCorrespondent + '">');
    var link = $('<a>');

    link.attr('href', '#');
    link.html(item.name + ' ' + milesFromCorrespondent + ' Miles');

    $(listItem).append(link);
    $(list).append(listItem);
});

// bind list events to page
$('#correspondentsByLocation').bind('pageinit', function () {
    $(list).listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr('data-distance');
            return out;
        }
    }).listview('refresh');
});
```

}

Comment: Autodividers don't help with sorting/ordering, they just group adjacent items with a common attribute (e.g. start with same letter). You will need to sort your correspondents by distance first and then append them to the listview in the correct order. You could also look at this plugin: http://andymatthews.net/code/jqm-tinysort/

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was hoping there would be something built into the listview that I just hadn't found yet, but I guess I'll just have to do it the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working:

```
function buildNearestCorrespondentList(correspondents, deviceLatitude, deviceLongitude) {
var list = $('#nearestCorrespondentsList');

// get distance from device for each coorespondent
$.each(correspondents, function (index, item) {
    var milesFromCorrespondent = distance(deviceLatitude, deviceLongitude, item.latitude, item.longitude);
    item.distance = milesFromCorrespondent;
});

// sort by closest
correspondents.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.distance > b.distance;
});

// populate list
$.each(correspondents, function (index, item) {
    var milesFromCorrespondent = distance(deviceLatitude, deviceLongitude, item.latitude, item.longitude);
    var listItem = $('<li data-distance="' + milesFromCorrespondent + '" class="nearest-correspondent">');
    var link = $('<a>');

    link.attr('href', '#');
    link.html('<span class="name">' + item.name + '</span>'
        + '<span class="locality">' + item.locality + '</span>'
        + '<span class="country">' + item.country + '</span>');

    $(listItem).append(link);
    $(list).append(listItem);
});

// bind list events to page
$('#correspondentsByLocation').bind('pageinit', function () {
    $(list).listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr('data-distance') + ' Miles';
            return out;
        }
    }).listview('refresh');
});

// refresh if already initialised
if (isListInitialised(list)) {
    list.listview('refresh');
}
```

}